# Getting the value of an enum field

Tags: java, enums, byte

I have an enumeration of byte values:

```
        public class ByteMessage {

            public enum Messages {
                ACK(0x01), CHAT(0x02), TURN(0x02), WAITING(0x03), REMATCH(0x04), DOUBLE(0x05), LOADREQUEST(0x06), LOADCOMPLETE(0x07),
                ROLL(0x08), DBLACCEPTORDECLINE(0x09), DBLRECV(0x0A), ALERTPEERNOPOSSIBLES(0x0B), UPDATEDIES(0x0C),
                SETTURN(0x0D), SETFIRSTROLL(0x0E), CALCPOSSIBLEINDEXES(0x0F), LOADGAMEREQUEST(0x10), LOADGAMECOMPLETE(0x11), PUSHSTATUSTEXT(0x12),
                ISDOUBLESOWNER(0x13);

                private final byte id;

                Messages(int id) {
                    this.id = (byte) id;
                }

                public byte getId() {
                    return this.id;
                }
            }
```

In another class I have this function:

```
            private void SendACK()
            {
                byte[] message = new byte[10];

                //Neither one of these will compile I have to return back the byte value of ACK
                //Byte a = new Byte(ByteMessage.M.ACK);
                //message[0] = ByteMessage.M.ACK;
```

Is there a way to get the byte value back out of the enum?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `getId` method of your `Message` enum :

```
message[0] = ByteMessage.M.ACK.getId();
```

Each constant in an `enum` is an instance of the `enum`. Just like classes, an instance of an `enum` can have data. In your specific case, each `enum` constant has an `id` which is initialized when the `enum` constant is created and can be accessed through the `getId` member method.